# Random 128 during git fetch --tags

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-github-plugin

Starting around a month ago? We started seeing *random* exit code 128 erros from git when fetching tags during checkout. We have tried clearing out known_hosts and adding the new fingerprints as that was the most obvious culprit, but she persists. I've also tried disabling credentials helper. Again, this happens randomly, it succeeds sometimes, and if I try to reproduce it in from the terminal, it usually succeeds.

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress -- git@github.com:Foo/bar.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```